# Display array of database records into select html tag

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have to pull the records inserted into a db row into an html select box so they have to appear into option tags.

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) { 
    require ('connect.php');

    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO lavoro (provincia,sede,settimana,giorno,ora) VALUES (:provincia,:sede,:settimana,:giorno,:ora)") or die ('Ciao1');
    $sql->execute(array(':provincia'=>$_POST['provincia'],':sede'=>$_POST['sede'],':settimana'=>$_POST['settimana'],':giorno'=>$_POST['giorno'],':ora'=>$_POST['ora'])) or die('Non aggiorna nulla');

    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option></option>';
    echo '</select>';
}
```

code OP posted in comments below

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 
    require ('connect.php'); 
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT sede FROM lavoro") or die ('Ciao1'); 
    $sql->execute(); 
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(); 
    print_r($result); 
    echo '<select>'; 
    echo '<option></option>'; 
    echo '</select>'; 
}
```

Comment: are you sure that shouldn't be a select rather than an insert query?

Comment: You have to fetch the result and use while loop.

Comment: How do you select records using insert query.

Comment: You guys are right. But Yogesh can you paste me a functioning example? I'm using the fetchAll() method but nothing happens...using PDO

Comment: Post your fetchAll() method, and we can help debug that, rather than make us write it for you.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  require ('connect.php');
  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT sede FROM lavoro") or die ('Ciao1');
  $sql->execute();
  
  $result = $sql->fetchAll();
  print_r($result);
  echo '<select>';
  echo '<option></option>';
  echo '</select>';
 }

Comment: Always put your code in the question, using the edit link, as code in comments is often hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your code in the comments, try something like

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 
    require ('connect.php'); 
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT sede FROM lavoro") or die ('Ciao1'); 
    $sql->execute(); 
    $result = $sql->fetchAll();  
    echo '<select name="sede">';
    foreach($result as $value){
            echo "<option value='{$value['sede']}'>{$value['sede']}</option>";
    } 
    echo '</select>'; 
}
```

Comment: Ok it works! Sorry Sean but, for the future, what is $value? i saw this a lot of times but i can't understand where is declared

Comment: `$value` in this case is just a random variable used in a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. It does not need to be declared before, just in the `foreach()` paramaters. You can use anything, ie. `$a`, `$option`, `$val`, `$hello`, etc.